# Как замокать метод расширения GetUserId(this IIdentity identity)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, mocking, moq

У приложения `ASP.NET-MVC + ASP.NET-WebAPI2 + ASP.NET-Identity 1` есть api-метод `Get`:

```
[Route("api/accounts")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{            
    var user = _dbContext.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    if(user.Roles.Count > 0)
    {
        var userRoles = user.Roles.Select(x => x.Role.Name);
        var model = new ApiViewModel
        {
            UserName = User.Identity.Name,
            UserRoleNames = userRoles
        };
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
    }
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "The user has no one role");
}
```

Хочу протестировать этот метод. Для данного метода необходимо, чтобы в контексте запроса был авторизованный пользователь. Я решил попробовать замокать вызов `User.Identity.GetUserId()` - получить Id существующего в БД пользователя:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetTest()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
    var mockIdentity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
    mockPrincipal.SetupGet(x => x.Identity).Returns(mockIdentity.Object);
    mockIdentity.Setup(x => x.GetUserId()).Returns("5dcf65f5-2e42");
    ...
```

И в ответ получил исключение:

> Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked
>   object: x => x.GetUserId()

---

### Вопрос

Есть ли возможность замокать вызов метода расширения или есть ли другой способ передать в контекст запроса `Get` авторизованного пользователя?

---

### Update

Обновил юнит-тест, согласно ответу @Pavel Mayorov:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetTest()
{
    //Arrange

    var mockIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
    mockIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "5dcf65f5-2e42"));
    var mockPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(mockIdentity);
    var controller = new AccountController
    {
        User = mockPrincipal
    };
    controller.User = mockPrincipal;

    //Act
    var result = controller.Get();
```

**+** вызов `User.Identity.GetUserId()` возвращает `5dcf65f5-2e42` что и требовалось.

**-** но дальше `Find` (`_dbContext.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId())`) возвращает `null`.

Почему во время теста? при передачи валидного `Id` `Find` вернул `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Этот метод ищет среди прочих утверждений (Claims) утверждение с именем `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`. Кстати, `IIdentity` - это объект-носитель данных, а не сервис, и мокать его нет смысла.

Поэтому проще всего создать новую ClaimsIdentity и добавить ей нужные утверждения:

```
var mockIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
mockIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "5dcf65f5-2e42"));

var mockPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(mockIdentity);
```

Comment: Я обновил вопрос